# Read files from HDFS without access to the data nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My group currently has a Hadoop cluster set up for testing (Cloudera) with primary and secondary namenodes that are accessible to everyone over the LAN and a few datanodes that are connected to a separate switch and not accessible over the LAN.

With this setup, I am able to connect to the namenodes from my developer laptop and do things having to do with file metadata, like getting a list of files in a directory. However, I can't read any actual file contents.

Is there any method that could allow me to read the file contents through the namenodes only? Or will I have to just bite the bullet and get the wonky networking setup fixed properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [HttpFS Gateway](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html), also called Hadoop HDFS over HTTP. By using this service, 100% compatible with webhdfs API, you will be able to perform *2-step* operations (i.e. those accessing the Namenode in first stage, then receiving a redirection to a Datanode, finally accessing such Datanode in second stage) by only accessing the node where HttpFS runs; this is because HttpFS points to itself in the redirections.

In your case, install HttpFS in a Namenode.

Comment: It works! I'm using some simple pywebhdfs code, and I can get back the files I need. I was fully expecting that I would have to do a bunch of network config to get all the nodes accessible, but HttpFS does exactly what I need. Thanks!